# Does a z-test make sense here?

Tags: statistical-significance, z-test

I have been assigned to collect data about the contents of an additive in wine. The additive is approved, but also fairly poisonous in the right amounts.

The dataset consists of test results for +3000 bottles tapped between 1999 and 2019. All tests were performed in 2020. The number of bottles per year varies. We test bottles from a variety of producers, but not necessarily the same producers or wines every year.

The additive was found in 41% of all bottles tested, but there is a lot of variance between years. We have observed the additive in between 35 % and maximum 46 % of the tested bottles per vintage. The values shift up and down between vintages, meaning that there is no growth or decline.

The thing that had caught my customer’s attention is that 2019 broke the record with the additive being present in 47.5% of all bottles.

The customer has, upon receiving the results, performed various statistical tests. One of them is a two proportion Z test which confirms that the gap between 2019 and the average for the rest of the vintages is statistically significant. According to our client, this suggests that wine makers have increased the usage of the additive.

I am however a bit skeptical about that conclusion. Although 2019 has the maximum value, we have observed a lot of variance between the previous years. To me it seems like a coincidence.

What should I tell my client?

Comment: Per this NYTimes comment: "Along with adding sugar for the purpose of sweetening wine, some producers add sugar before or during fermentation in order to achieve a certain alcohol level. This process is called chaptalization, and it is more common in cooler wine regions such as Oregon, where grapes ripen more slowly."  I would expect a relationship between avg growing temperature and sweetness/alcohol content. However, with global warming, the chemistry underlying the wine properties/mix changes. No adding of sugar required for the composition of wine to change. Offer this explanation.

Comment: The additive in question isn’t sugar, and I’m not sure the explanation would make sense then

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it appears that the hypothesis tested was "the proportion of bottles with the additive present in 2019 was greater than the average proportion of bottles with the additive present over all previous years". If I am interpreting you correctly, you actually want to know if the data generating process (in this case adding the additive) changed in 2019 from previous years, or if the high in 2019 is plausibly just a result of random variation.

If this is the case, you could do the following to demonstrate your case:

- Fit a binomial distribution to your data, where each observation is the pair consisting of the count of bottles with the additive for a given year and the total count of bottles for a given year.
- Simulate a large number (e.g. 10,000) of random draws from the binomial distribution where the total count of bottles is equal to the total count from 2019, and calculate the proportion for each simulation.
- Calculate the proportion of simulated proportions that are greater than the 2019 proportion.

The closer this proportion is to 0%, the less likely it was that the 2019 value came from the data generating process given by the model. Classically if the proportion is less than or equal to 5%, we would deem the difference "statistically significant".

What follows is some R code that would solve this for you.

Since I don't have your data, the first part of my code generates some fake data akin to your real data.

```
# Your post mentions years 1999 through 2019.
year <- 1999:2019

# Your post mentions 3000+ bottles
grand_count_of_total_bottles <- 3000

# Multinomial distribution will simply spread 3000 bottles randomly across the years.
count_of_total_bottles <- rmultinom(n = 1, 
                                    size = grand_count_of_total_bottles, 
                                    prob = rep(1/length(year), length(year)))

# Your post mentions a grand mean of 41%
grand_prop_of_bottles_with_additive <- .41
                          
# Binomial distribution gives us a random number of bottles with additives each year.
count_of_bottles_with_additive <- rbinom(n = length(count_of_total_bottles),
                                         size = count_of_total_bottles,
                                         prob = grand_prop_of_bottles_with_additive)
```

With our fake data in tow, we can do the proposed calculations.

````
# Maximum likelihood estimator for the probability parameter of a binomial distribution.
mle_prob <- sum(count_of_bottles_with_additive)/sum(count_of_total_bottles) 

# Simulate a large number of possible bottles with additives given the 2019 total count.
sim_count_of_bottles_with_additive <- rbinom(n = 10000, 
                                             size = count_of_total_bottles[year == 2019],
                                             prob = mle_prob)

# Get the simulated proportions 
sim_prop_of_bottles_with_additive <- sim_count_of_bottles_with_additive / count_of_total_bottles[year == 2019]

# Get 2019's proportion
prop_for_2019 <- count_of_bottles_with_additive[year == 2019]/count_of_total_bottles[year == 2019]

# Compute the proportion of simulated proportions that are greater than 2019's proportion.
prop_of_sim_prop_gt_2019_prop <- mean(sim_prop_of_bottles_with_additive > prop_for_2019)

# Determine if 2019 is statistically significantly different at the 5% level
prop_of_sim_prop_gt_2019_prop <= .05

```
````

Comment: That’s absolutely right. I don’t do R-code but we may be able to construct something in excel

Comment: Excellent! Yes, you should be able to do exactly the same thing with excel. I believe the RAND and BINOM.INV functions will suffice for the simulation component. Unfortunately my knowledge of excel is inversely proportional to my knowledge of R, so I don't know for sure.